# Firebird: How to make an md5 hash?

Tags: firebird

I want to update all passwords in the DB to have a MD5 hashes password. The following doesn't solve my problem:

```
UPDATE USERS SET USERPASS = hash('SALT' || USERPASS);
```

Problem being: it returns a hash that was not generated using the MD5 algorithm. How can I impliment the md5 hash algorithm in Firebird?

Comment: As far as I know the `HASH` function in Firebird is not a cryptographic hash, but more like the `hashcode()` function that exists in Java. Also: you really should not be using MD5 for passwords, use something stronger like pbkdf2, bcrypt or scrypt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately the algorithm of the `hash` function is not mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref25/fblangref25-functions-string.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-hash). Anyway, you can implement it as an UDF or use some third-party UDF library which implements it. There is a list of [UDF Libraries for Firebird](https://web.archive.org/web/20231004123532/https://ibphoenix.com/download/tools/udf) on the IBPhoenix website and it seems that both rFunc and FreeAdhocUDF library have one (I only checked these two, there is probably others).

Comment: What about sha256 or sha512 ?

Comment: On the IBPhoenix website list includes `fb_mhash / fb_shash` which is described as "implements an interface to the mhash library (libmhash)". The [mhash](http://mhash.sourceforge.net/) supports both sha256 and sha512 so it seems to fit the bill. The link on the  IBPhoenix website is broken but google found this: http://nixbit.com/cat/programming/libraries/fb-mhash/

Comment: the hash algo said to be "ELF" whatever that is

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PJW_hash_function says "A variant of PJW hash had been used to create ElfHash or Elf64 hash that is used in UNIX object files with ELF format."

Answer (score 5):

Firebird 4.0 has added cryptographic hash functions. To quote from the [Firebird 4.0 release notes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html):

> #### CRYPT_HASH()
>
> Alex Peshkov
>
> Accepts an argument than can be a field, variable or expression of any
> type recognized by DSQL/PSQL and returns a cryptographic hash
> calculated from the input argument using the specified algorithm.
> Syntax
>
> ```
> CRYPT_HASH( <any value> USING <algorithm> )
>
> <algorithm> ::= { MD5 | SHA1 | SHA256 | SHA512 }
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```sql
> select crypt_hash(job_title using sha256) from job;
> ```
>
> NOTE
>
> - This function returns a VARBINARY string with the length depending on the specified algorithm.
> - MD5 and SHA1 algorithms are not recommended due to known severe issues, these algorithms are provided for backward compatibility ONLY.

Firebird 4 can be downloaded from https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-4-0/

See also the [`CRYPT_HASH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-functions-string.html#fblangref40-scalarfuncs-crypthash) documentation in the Firebird 4.0 Language Reference.

Answer (score 4):

Here is another way without UDF, I found [here](https://www.sql.ru/forum/1145053/md5-bez-udf)

```
/******************************************************************************/
/***          Generated by IBExpert 2018.6.8.1 27.08.2018 16:31:02          ***/
/******************************************************************************/

/******************************************************************************/
/***      Following SET SQL DIALECT is just for the Database Comparer       ***/
/******************************************************************************/
SET SQL DIALECT 3;



/******************************************************************************/
/***                           Stored procedures                            ***/
/******************************************************************************/



SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5 (
    SOURCE BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80 CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
BEGIN
  SUSPEND;
END^





CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_F (
    A BIGINT,
    B BIGINT,
    C BIGINT,
    D BIGINT,
    K INTEGER,
    S INTEGER,
    T BIGINT,
    P INTEGER,
    V CHAR(64) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
RETURNS (
    RES BIGINT)
AS
BEGIN
  SUSPEND;
END^





CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_INTTOCHAR4 (
    V BIGINT)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(4) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
BEGIN
  SUSPEND;
END^





CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_INTTOHEX (
    V BIGINT)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
BEGIN
  SUSPEND;
END^






SET TERM ; ^



/******************************************************************************/
/***                           Stored procedures                            ***/
/******************************************************************************/



SET TERM ^ ;

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5 (
    SOURCE BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 80 CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
declare variable A bigint = 0X0067452301;
declare variable B bigint = 0X00EFCDAB89;
declare variable C bigint = 0X0098BADCFE;
declare variable D bigint = 0X0010325476;
declare variable AA bigint;
declare variable BB bigint;
declare variable CC bigint;
declare variable DD bigint;
declare variable BUF char(64) character set OCTETS;
declare variable LEN bigint;
declare variable M integer;
declare variable N integer;
begin
  len = octet_length(source);
  m = 56 - mod(len + 1, 64);
  if (m < 0) then m = m + 64;
  source = source || rpad(x'80', m+1, x'00') ||
    (select res from md5_IntToChar4(bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, bin_shl(:len, 3)))) ||
    (select res from md5_IntToChar4(bin_shr(:len, 32-3)));

  n = 0;
  while (n < (len+m+9) / 64) do
  begin
    AA = A;
    BB = B;
    CC = C;
    DD = D;

    buf = substring(source from n * 64 + 1 for 64);

    /* Round 1 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  0,  7, 0x00d76aa478, 1, :buf)); /* 1 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  1, 12, 0x00e8c7b756, 1, :buf)); /* 2 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  2, 17, 0x00242070db, 1, :buf)); /* 3 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  3, 22, 0x00c1bdceee, 1, :buf)); /* 4 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  4,  7, 0x00f57c0faf, 1, :buf)); /* 5 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  5, 12, 0x004787c62a, 1, :buf)); /* 6 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  6, 17, 0x00a8304613, 1, :buf)); /* 7 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  7, 22, 0x00fd469501, 1, :buf)); /* 8 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  8,  7, 0x00698098d8, 1, :buf)); /* 9 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  9, 12, 0x008b44f7af, 1, :buf)); /* 10 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 10, 17, 0x00ffff5bb1, 1, :buf)); /* 11 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 11, 22, 0x00895cd7be, 1, :buf)); /* 12 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D, 12,  7, 0x006b901122, 1, :buf)); /* 13 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 13, 12, 0x00fd987193, 1, :buf)); /* 14 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 14, 17, 0x00a679438e, 1, :buf)); /* 15 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 15, 22, 0x0049b40821, 1, :buf)); /* 16 */

    /* Round 2 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  1,  5, 0x00f61e2562, 2, :buf)); /* 17 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  6,  9, 0x00c040b340, 2, :buf)); /* 18 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 11, 14, 0x00265e5a51, 2, :buf)); /* 19 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  0, 20, 0x00e9b6c7aa, 2, :buf)); /* 20 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  5,  5, 0x00d62f105d, 2, :buf)); /* 21 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 10,  9, 0x0002441453, 2, :buf)); /* 22 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 15, 14, 0x00d8a1e681, 2, :buf)); /* 23 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  4, 20, 0x00e7d3fbc8, 2, :buf)); /* 24 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  9,  5, 0x0021e1cde6, 2, :buf)); /* 25 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 14,  9, 0x00c33707d6, 2, :buf)); /* 26 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  3, 14, 0x00f4d50d87, 2, :buf)); /* 27 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  8, 20, 0x00455a14ed, 2, :buf)); /* 28 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D, 13,  5, 0x00a9e3e905, 2, :buf)); /* 29 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  2,  9, 0x00fcefa3f8, 2, :buf)); /* 30 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  7, 14, 0x00676f02d9, 2, :buf)); /* 31 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 12, 20, 0x008d2a4c8a, 2, :buf)); /* 32 */

    /* Round 3 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  5,  4, 0x00fffa3942, 3, :buf)); /* 33 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  8, 11, 0x008771f681, 3, :buf)); /* 34 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 11, 16, 0x006d9d6122, 3, :buf)); /* 35 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 14, 23, 0x00fde5380c, 3, :buf)); /* 36 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  1,  4, 0x00a4beea44, 3, :buf)); /* 37 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  4, 11, 0x004bdecfa9, 3, :buf)); /* 38 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  7, 16, 0x00f6bb4b60, 3, :buf)); /* 39 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 10, 23, 0x00bebfbc70, 3, :buf)); /* 40 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D, 13,  4, 0x00289b7ec6, 3, :buf)); /* 41 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  0, 11, 0x00eaa127fa, 3, :buf)); /* 42 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  3, 16, 0x00d4ef3085, 3, :buf)); /* 43 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  6, 23, 0x0004881d05, 3, :buf)); /* 44 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  9,  4, 0x00d9d4d039, 3, :buf)); /* 45 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 12, 11, 0x00e6db99e5, 3, :buf)); /* 46 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 15, 16, 0x001fa27cf8, 3, :buf)); /* 47 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  2, 23, 0x00c4ac5665, 3, :buf)); /* 48 */

    /* Round 4 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  0,  6, 0x00f4292244, 4, :buf)); /* 49 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  7, 10, 0x00432aff97, 4, :buf)); /* 50 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 14, 15, 0x00ab9423a7, 4, :buf)); /* 51 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  5, 21, 0x00fc93a039, 4, :buf)); /* 52 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D, 12,  6, 0x00655b59c3, 4, :buf)); /* 53 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C,  3, 10, 0x008f0ccc92, 4, :buf)); /* 54 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B, 10, 15, 0x00ffeff47d, 4, :buf)); /* 55 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  1, 21, 0x0085845dd1, 4, :buf)); /* 56 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  8,  6, 0x006fa87e4f, 4, :buf)); /* 57 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 15, 10, 0x00fe2ce6e0, 4, :buf)); /* 58 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  6, 15, 0x00a3014314, 4, :buf)); /* 59 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A, 13, 21, 0x004e0811a1, 4, :buf)); /* 60 */
    A = (select res from md5_F(:A, :B, :C, :D,  4,  6, 0x00f7537e82, 4, :buf)); /* 61 */
    D = (select res from md5_F(:D, :A, :B, :C, 11, 10, 0x00bd3af235, 4, :buf)); /* 62 */
    C = (select res from md5_F(:C, :D, :A, :B,  2, 15, 0x002ad7d2bb, 4, :buf)); /* 63 */
    B = (select res from md5_F(:B, :C, :D, :A,  9, 21, 0x00eb86d391, 4, :buf)); /* 64 */

    A = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, AA + A);
    B = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, BB + B);
    C = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, CC + C);
    D = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, DD + D);
    n = n + 1;
  end

  res =
    (select res from md5_IntToHex(:a))||
    (select res from md5_IntToHex(:b))||
    (select res from md5_IntToHex(:c))||
    (select res from md5_IntToHex(:d));
    suspend;
end^


CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_F (
    A BIGINT,
    B BIGINT,
    C BIGINT,
    D BIGINT,
    K INTEGER,
    S INTEGER,
    T BIGINT,
    P INTEGER,
    V CHAR(64) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
RETURNS (
    RES BIGINT)
AS
declare variable FF bigint;
declare variable R bigint;
declare variable X bigint;
begin
  X = bin_or(ascii_val(substring(V from k*4 + 1 for 1)),
             bin_shl(ascii_val(substring(V from k*4 + 2 for 1)), 8),
             bin_shl(ascii_val(substring(V from k*4 + 3 for 1)),16),
             bin_shl(ascii_val(substring(V from k*4 + 4 for 1)),24));

  if (p = 1) then /* f */
    ff = bin_or(bin_and(b, c), bin_and(bin_not(b), d));
  if (p = 2) then /* g */
    ff = bin_or(bin_and(b, d), bin_and(bin_not(d), c));
  if (p = 3) then /* h */
    ff = bin_xor(b, c, d);
  if (p = 4) then /* i */
    ff = bin_xor(c, bin_or(bin_not(d), b));

  r = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, a + ff + x + t);
  r = bin_and(0x00FFFFFFFF, b + bin_or(bin_shl(r, s), bin_shr(r, 32 - s)));
  res = r;
  suspend;
end^


CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_INTTOCHAR4 (
    V BIGINT)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(4) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
begin
  res =  ascii_char(bin_and(0xFF, V))||
         ascii_char(bin_and(0xFF, bin_shr(V, 8)))||
         ascii_char(bin_and(0xFF, bin_shr(V, 16)))||
         ascii_char(bin_and(0xFF, bin_shr(V, 24)));
  suspend;
end^


CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MD5_INTTOHEX (
    V BIGINT)
RETURNS (
    RES CHAR(8) CHARACTER SET OCTETS)
AS
declare variable H char(16) = '0123456789ABCDEF';
begin
  res = substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 4))+1 for 1) ||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, V)+1  for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 12))+1 for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 8))+1 for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 20))+1 for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 16))+1 for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 28))+1 for 1)||
        substring(h from bin_and(0x0F, bin_shr(V, 24))+1 for 1);
  suspend;
end^



SET TERM ; ^
```