# "invalid use of vertical bars" error in Access query

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

this is my select in python with pyodbc

```
SELECT = "SELECT k.ID as id, k.Title as title, hash(k.ID || k.Title) as hash from kart as k"
```

where I get error

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid use of vertical bars in query expression 'hash(k.ID || k.Title)'. (-3100) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Any idea how to solve it please? This select I use for my FDB without problem. Problem must be in vertical bar and hash function. What is alternative for this in Access?

Comment: There is no `hash()` function in Access SQL.

Comment: When you say you use it with "your FDB" do you mean a Firebird database?

Comment: yes, exactly, Firebird database (but with another python module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there is no built-in `HASH()` function in Access SQL. If you need to create a hash value corresponding to the one returned by the `HASH()` function in Firebird then you'll need to dig up some code to do the calculation yourself. There might be some leads for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17927146/2144390).

For reference, the double vertical bars (`||`) are apparently the string contatenation operator in Firebird. The equivalent in Access SQL is the ampersand (`&`) character.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a PC setting issue. Please check on the `separator` setting. Here are the navigation steps -- Control Panel --> Region and Language --> Additional Settings --> List separator --> `,` (Most likely it was set to `|`)